# How can I load a local file from embedded Rhino?

Tags: rhino, embedding

I'm using Rhino's `context.evaluateString()` to run some simple JavaScript from inside of Java.  It's textbook right out of the [Embedding Javascript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial):

```
String script = // simple logic
Context c = new ContextFactory().enterContext();
ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
Object o = context.evaluateString(scope, script, "myScript", 1, null);
ScriptableObject result = Context.jsToJava(o, ScriptableObject.class);
```

I'm not sure this is the current best-practice, because the main Rhino docs appear to be down, but it's working so far.

I'd like to be able to refer to a library in the working directory -- I see that [Rhino shell supports `load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Shell) but I don't think this works in the embedding engine.

Is this possible?  Is it documented anywhere?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to just call something like `load('other.js')` and have it search directories I specify as a global property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sort-of answer that I don't really like, not least because it exposes what I'm pretty sure is a Rhino bug that drove me crazy for the last half hour:

```
eval("" + Packages.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(
  new java.io.File("/the/local/root", "script.js");
));
```

{ That `"" + ...` is how I work around the bug -- if you `eval()` a Java `String` (such as is returned from the `readFileToString` call) without manually coercing it to a JavaScript native string, nothing appears to happen.  The call just silently fails. }

This blindly reads an arbitrary file and evals it -- of course, this is what you do when you `eval()` from the Java side, so I don't worry about it too much.

Anyway, it's not elegant for a number of reasons, but it *works*.  I'd love to hear a better answer!